# Slickgrid: Multiple Grouping with dynamic Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, parameter-passing, slickgrid

I am working on [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) JS plugin. And i want to dynamically group the Grid/Table based on the table header. How should I pass the parameters `[getter,formatter, aggregators]` dynamically

without hard coding like this

```
dataView.setGrouping([
    {
        getter : "department",
        collapsed : false,
        formatter : function(g){
            return g.value;
        },
        comparer : groupComparer
    },{
        getter : "faculty",
        collapsed : false,
        formatter : function(g){
            return g.value;
        },
        comparer : groupComparer
    }
]);
```

Is it possible to use any looping statements to generate `Array` of parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried much, and found this solution

```
            arr=["department","faculty"];       //Dynamically generated array having titles to group
            var ar = []; //empty array to push parameters                                           
            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {                                       
                ar[i] = {
                        getter: arr[i],
                        formatter: function (g) {                               
                                return ":  " + g.value + "  <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items)</span>";
                        },      
                        aggregators: [
                            new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Avg("percentComplete"),
                            new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("cost")
                        ],
                        aggregateCollapsed: false,
                        lazyTotalsCalculation: false
                      };                      
            }               
            dataView.setGrouping(ar);
```